# Ways of reversing motor direction easily

Tags: motor

My set up consists of a brushed motor (ex cordless drill type) connected to a motor controller which is in turn connected to a LIPO battery and an r/c receiver. All my cables are fitted with XT 60 connectors except for the cable that goes to the receiver which is a 3 wire pin (usual white, red and black).

The above set up is one of a pair which I am using in my battle robot. The motors are connected to drive wheels, left and right respectively. the problem is the motors are turning in opposing directions.

For some reason I neglected to switch the polarity of the wires of one  motor at the time I attached the XT 60 connectors and I really am not looking forward to re-soldering.

So my question is whether there is any fast way of reversing the direction of rotation without soldering?  For instance can the R/C transmitter (a turnigy 9x without any modding)be programmed to switch up for down (hence forward for reverse)?

Or can I maybe switch the pin connector going into the receiver (I don't think so because the ground is probably common, but worth asking just in case I guess).

Any ideas or should I just get soldering?

Comment: Are you using an h-bridge?

Comment: Paul, I am using this motor controller. I don't think it is an H-bridge. http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/320A-7-2V-16V-High-Voltage-ESC-Brushed-Speed-Controller-for-RC-Car-Truck-Boat-UK-/390820623587?ssPageName=ADME:X:RTQ:GB:1123

Comment: 320 Amp! each channel! that must be a serious robot! Deep inside, it is indeed an H-bridge, as about every speed controller is.

Comment: I seriously doubt the 320A rating is right though since the power cables are pretty standard 12AWG gauge!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Turnigy 9x and just about every RC transmitter can reverse channels. Look for Servo setup, reverse.  Step 9.1 in [9x manual](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uploads/529892926x11510x49.pdf)

This assumes your left and right motors are on different channels. If you used a v-tail mixer to obtain turtle drive, you will have to experiment with it's set-up instead (9.17).